# HQL - Nesting HashMaps

Tags: java, hibernate, coldfusion, hql

In the below HQL, my end goal is to create a map of 2 Center properties, whilst being grouped by the Business it resides under. Trying a few different scenarios, I came up with the idea of a Map within a Map (which doesn't seem to be possible, but it's what closely represented my desired outcome.

```
SELECT new map (b.businessDisplay as group, new map (c.centerID as value, c.centerDisplay as text) as values)
FROM Center c
JOIN FETCH c.business b
ORDER BY b.businessName, c.centerName
```

Trying to do as much as I can with hibernate, the end result I am looking for is of the following:

```
{
   "group":"Business A",
   "values":[
      {
         "text":"Center A",
         "value":1
      },
      {
         "text":"Center B",
         "value":2
      }
   ]
}
```

Is this outcome possible, or am I looking to simplify the HQL and structure my data once it's retrieved?